# SwiftUI Image not filling widget

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget

I'm struggling to fit an entire image into a widget without it leaving out edges.

```
struct QuoteWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Image(entry.quotes)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

As seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtOJ5.jpg

Any ideas on how to fix this.

I tried experimenting with below but did not get it to work.

```
 .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```